# Run and Wait for async Task to complete in a Windows Form Application

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

How can I wait for an async task to complete without freezing the whole Application?

This function works but Cout() gets called while the File is still downloading.

```
private void Btn_test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    var task = Task.Run(async () => { await DownloadWebFile("https://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "//100MB.bin"); });
        
     Cout(DownloadSuccessMsg);    
}
```

when I do this the whole Application freezes:

```
private void Btn_test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    var task = Task.Run(async () => { await DownloadWebFile("https://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "//100MB.bin"); });
    task.Wait();     
    Cout(DownloadSuccessMsg);    
}
```

How can I wait correctly before running other code depending on the downloaded file?

```
private static async Task DownloadWebFile(string url, string fullPath)
{
     using var client = new DownloadManager(url, fullPath);
        client.ProgressChanged += (totalFileSize, totalBytesDownloaded, progressPercentage) =>
        {
            SetProgressBarValue((int)progressPercentage);
        };

    await client.StartDownload();            
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can mark the method as `async void`. Returning `void` from an asynchronous method is usually not a great idea, but in the case of an event handler it's usually considered acceptable.

```
private async void Btn_test_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    await DownloadWebFile("https://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "//100MB.bin");
    Cout(DownloadSuccessMsg); 
}
```

Comment: Please don't encourage the practice of `catch (Exception ex)`. It's awful. Why introduce exception handling here when the OP didn't have it?

Comment: I didn't say not to have error handling. I specifically meant that catching `Exception` is a horrible thing to do. You should only ever catch ***specific*** exceptions that you can ***meaningfully*** handle. Have a read of this: https://ericlippert.com/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/

Comment: @Enigmativity Yes, and I agree. I've had errors that were unrecoverable but were caught regardless leaving the application in a bad state. I would have written a more specific exception handler but I wasn't sure what's in `DownloadWebFile`. This of course then begged the question, why show error handling at all. So in light of that I removed the offending code. I've read that blog post from Eric before (I've read a lot of his posts over the years actually).

Comment: @Enigmativity could you give a suggestion about how to handle an exception in the `Btn_test_Click` event handler? I guess that you don't want the app to just crash, with a stack trace thrown in the face of the user...

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - I would look at what specific exceptions I could meaningfully handle.

Comment: @Enigmativity so your suggestion regarding unexpected types of exceptions (exceptions that have not been observed during the debugging/testing), is to let them crash the application in the production environment?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias you could imagine that the OP is using an `HttpClient` in `DownloadWebFile`, in this case catching an `HttpRequestException` would be acceptable.

Comment: I think in this case, using `Exception` instead of a more derived type could hide either programmer errors or unrecoverable errors which your application really can't handle.

Comment: @WBuck how about an `ArgumentException` or a `NullReferenceException`, caused by an erroneous configuration setting, or a rare unobserved bug? Are you OK with the users seeing [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n6mA5.png) message in their screen?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Pretty much, yes. Unexpected exceptions are, well, unexpected. Over many years of coding you learn what might be expected and code for those. If you just go about your coding by putting in exception handlers for all ***unexpected*** exceptions then you just bloat your code ***and you are likely to introduce errors***. The number 1 predictor of bugs in your code is the number of lines of code you write. Write less code. Let exceptions fly. Learn what to really expect. Handle those. Become a craftsman.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Yes, I like those exceptions. It lets me know I've coded something poorly and allows me to fix it. Throwing in `catch (Exception ex)` to prevent that also prevents me learning and writing better code.

Comment: @Enigmativity it seems that you are talking from the perspective of someone who is the only consumer of the program they write. What about a program that you release and deploy to thousands of users? Are you OK with letting the users see the generic *"Unexpected exception has occurred in your application..."* popup?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Asked and answered.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - But, you are more or less right. I code the internal apps for my organisation. I'm not releasing mass consumption software. If I were I'd be trying to avoid error handling where possible, i.e. code around errors, and provide good top-level, consumer friendly, error handling.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - There does seem to be a mass delusion about error handling. I think many junior programmers throw in a lot of error handling when they don't know how to handle errors and then they get into bad habits.

Comment: @Enigmativity *"i.e. code around errors, and provide good top-level, consumer friendly, error handling."* -- Could you explain what do you mean be that? How would you implement this type of top-level error handling, that will also be consumer friendly? I assume that if you have a UI with 50 buttons that each one does something different, displaying the same generic error message in all kinds of unexpected exceptions would not be considered consumer friendly!

Comment: @Enigmativity btw my own experience of developing GUI applications was in a company with ~3,000 customers and a help center with ~10 employees, that received phone calls and emails whenever an error had occurred. The application had `try`-`catch (Exception ex)` blocks in all UI related event handlers (hundreds of them), and displayed the `ex.Message` along with the action that caused the exception. So receiving a screenshot with an exception message provided immediate and accurate information about the button that was clicked and caused the exception. No need to ask the customer for this info.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - Something like this: https://pastebin.com/J9gWpfx1

Comment: @Enigmativity yep, that's what I expected. Handling the static `Application.ThreadException` event allows to customize the appearance of the unhandled exception message, but doesn't allow to pass any additional information regarding the UI event that caused the error. It won't make any easier to track the origins of the error, without exposing the stack trace to the user.

Comment: @Enigmativity my point is that the rule *"never `catch (Exception ex)`, it's horrible."* does not apply automatically on event handlers of GUI applications. Depending on the profile of your target users, it might be your best option. If there is one place where the `catch (Exception ex)` might be acceptable, this place is the event handlers of GUI applications.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias - OK, I concede. One top-level catch all is acceptable.